# Hindi font not displying correctly in android

Tags: android, sqlite, format, truetype, hindi

I want to display hindi text. The hindi data is fetched from the database sqlite, the same value when fetched from database , displays the word incorrectly though the font in the db in the correct hindi format.

Comment: God knows that the words may be in hindi & u fetched them in french format. How can one know without looking at what your code is

Comment: tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DroidHindi.ttf");
  textHeader.setTypeface(tf);
  textHindiWebLink.setTypeface(tf);
  textHeader.setText("कोंकण रेलवे");
  textHindiWebLink.setText("हिंदी वेबसाइट");

the first textview diplays properly , the second does not

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is copy a hindi font into your assets folder and create a custom typeface and apply that to the textView.

**Example:**

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font.ttf");
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appName);
text.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 2):

For Eclipse IDE : below is path to configure the encoding :

> Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding "Choose utf-8"

- create an array under the value folder
- Use the font that support Hindi under the assets folder
- `textview.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Hindi.ttf"));` its working fine
- for type hindi fastly use Google Inputtools for windows os [Download Here](http://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/)

Comment: i tried the encoding but it does not work for me.